# angular routes not directly accessible in nginx

Tags: angularjs, nginx

Here's the deal: I set up the simplest nginx configuration for practicing angular and I configured the routeProvider to use html5mode. So far, so good! I set the base to '/', my links to /view1 and /view2 works fine, but only when I click these links in my index page. When I try to access them directly in the browser (or reload the page), nginx returns me a 403 forbidden. That's a simple configuration but I can't find a simple explanation about it :(

I want to set things up in a way that any route works fine without have to explicitly set it (one by one) in my nginx site.conf. By the way, permissions are good !

Here's the actual conf file:

```
server {
    listen  *:80;
    server_name rbs.ang;
    root    /_dev/angularjs/app;
    index   index.html;
    charset UTF-8;

    location / {
        expires -1;
        add_header  Pragma "no-cache";
        add_header  Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
        try_files   $uri $uri/ index.html;
   }
}
```

Comment: You probably need to configure your server to redirect any request after / to index.html

Comment: As @Wawy, said just add a rule to nginx that when any request to `/*` is made, nginx has to serve index.html. AngularJS will take care of the rest

Comment: I just added a rule, but no luck, maybe I´m doing something wrong, can you please help me with this rule ?

Comment: Try `try_files $uri /$uri /index.html` Note the forward slash before `index.html`

Comment: It worked putting this line in both rules, thanks a lot !

Comment: @allienx Please make an answer since it is difficult to see the answers from comments.

Comment: The solution for this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38991541/nginx-and-angular-2). For me the Tyler Berry solution works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure a fallback route on your server to serve index.html file when a route is not matched.
This works:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: for spa not working