# Angular routing when directly browsed are not found

Tags: angular, hosting, angular-routing

So I defined some routes /home, /contact, ...
Created the dist folder by using `ng build --prod --base-href` and copied the content of the dist folder via filezilla to the hosting server. When directly browsing the website and redirecting from on the website there is no problem but if you directly browse to website/home, it says `404 Not Found The requested URL /home was not found on this server`.

The hosting support responded with these are probably CleanURL's defined in a .htaccess file we can't give support for that.

I thought that clean urls were readable restcalls but maybe the meaning is greater than only rest. But is there a solution for this?

Comment: do you add in the index.html <base href="/">

Comment: what webserver do you use? it is likely that you need some additional configuration (rules) to enable directly targeting your routes. See here for example (nginx): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38991541/nginx-and-angular-2

Comment: like @Riscie say if you don't config the server for url rewrite this will not work

Comment: just a standard linux hosting service and yes basehref is defined as /, the hosting is from [combell](https://www.combell.com/en/hosting/web-hosting)

Comment: your webserver is IIS ?.

Comment: [the first one here](https://www.combell.com/en/hosting/web-hosting/specifications)

Comment: in IIS you have to install URL Rewrite, I think similar you have to install in linux also

Comment: and what about creating a `.htaccess ` file shouldn't that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

more likely you have not defined the HashLocationStrategy in your providers (in app.module.ts)

Updated here.. i tried to put into the comments but it can't format

There are 3 ways 
1st way

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,..
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }) 
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, ...
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

2nd way

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, ...
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule, ...
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
  ],
  entryComponents: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

3rd way - recommended for Angular2 
Use PathLocationStrategy

```
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/my/app'}]
})
```

There are pros and cons - i used 2nd as I came from angular1, 2,4,5 (old school) :p

Comment: So I have to do `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})` instead of just giving in the routes then?

Comment: yes, see updated text above (I tried to comment here but i can't format).

Comment: method 1 and 2 give: http://localhost:4200/#/home a /#/ between my existing routes, 3rd way works locally I'll try on the apache server, do I still need a .htaccess file which redirects direct browsing to clean urls to index.html?

Comment: in theory, no. because if your current settings go to your app, the routing will handle the rest for you.  
p/s i didn't use apache. i m using nodejs express to serve our REST requests

Comment: my '' route redirects to '/home' so that's probably why it happend but It works so thanks.