# Angular 4 Routing works for me, but not my team

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

The problem - the routing works just fine for me. When I go to localhost/filecabinet, is goes to my filecabinet component. As it should. However, I've checked my code into source control. My team gets the code and goes to the same path and it takes them to the dashboard component. As if it can't find the route?

So I'm really at a loss. It's as if I haven't checked a file into source control that they need maybe? I really don't know. Any thoughts? Wish I had more to go on, but I'm confused?

Here's my app.routing.ts file:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './Dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { FileCabinetComponent } from './File-Cabinet/file- 
cabinet.component';
import { FileUploadComponent } from './File-Cabinet/file-upload.component';

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot([
{ path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
{ path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
{ path: 'filecabinet', component: FileCabinetComponent },
{ path: 'filecabinet/add', component: FileUploadComponent },
{ path: 'filecabinet/edit/:id', component: FileUploadComponent },
{ path: '**', component: DashboardComponent },
]);
//], { enableTracing: true });
```

Comment: Double-check versions of installed packages

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38991541/nginx-and-angular-2?noredirect=1&lq=1) out. This might be your problem.

Comment: Not sure what NGINX is, but I'm not using it?

Comment: Would suggest your team to do do `npm install` and then `ng serve` again.

Comment: I think It's web server problem not application problem

Comment: Can you tell me more Vala? we are using IIS

Comment: 1. Are you directly entering the route path in the address path or doing some activity (say a button click) on the dashboard and the Angular takes you to the route path? 
2. do you have a packacge-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json in your root folder?

Comment: It's directly into the browser. no clicks

Comment: Is your team using a different server than you? or it is the same server? do you have a packacge-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json in your root folder?

Comment: It seems your team's server is not configured to treat this particular url as an Angular route. So basically, you need to forward the Angular routes to index.html at the server level. For e.g. 

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), { req });
});

Here all routes (*) is treated as Angular route

Comment: @SaptarshiBasu That sounds correct. How is that done in IIS?

Comment: Don't know about IIS. Have done in Java and Node only. But the idea is to forward any request comes to that URL to index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the problem is cause it's case-sensitive and I did not know that?

I use the path http://localhost:56110/filecabinet
They used the path http://localhost:56110/FileCabinet

Comment: In advice use "dash separating" instead of "camel case" see [this](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/41595/what-is-the-casing-convention-for-url-routes)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing 
`{ path: '', component: DashboardComponent }` to `{ path: '', component: DashboardComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }`

Comment: this didn't help